# A 'doubl*e' data-type value giving me an incorrect subtraction result

Tags: vba

I'm just trying to subtract two 'double' data-type values but the result seems incorrect.

Here's the code:

```
    '// CAPACITY (VOLUME) COMPUTATION
    Dim minCap  As Double
    Dim maxCap  As Double
    Dim diffCap As Double
    
    minCap = rng_minHeight.Offset(0, 1).Value
    maxCap = rng_maxHeight.Offset(0, 1).Value
    diffCap = maxCap - minCap

    Debug.Print "Min Capacity: "; minCap
    Debug.Print "Max Capacity: "; maxCap
    Debug.Print "Difference: "; diffCap
```

and here's the result:

[image]

If you will calculate the two values: 307.203 - 307.185 = 0.018

Comment: Welcome to floating point math :-) If needed you can `WorksheetFunction.Round` to a certain amount of decimal places.

Comment: As you have no more than four decimals, _Dim_ the variables as _Currency_.

Comment: Hi guys, Thank you for your suggestions. I solved it by declaring the variable as Variant and the values converted using CDec keyword.